# Randomly pick a key value from an array

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Need some expertise help,

I'm trying to see if there is a way to randomly pick a attribute from an array doing a chef client run.

Example, 
I have this attribute

```
default['collectors_a'] = { a, b, c, d, e}
```

and In the recipe I want to randomly choose one of this element from the array.

Does anyone know how to go about it?

Thanks so much for helping out!!!!

Answer (score 1):

So a few issues, `{...}` is for a Hash, not an Array. In Ruby an Array literal looks like `[...]`, like `[1, 2, 3]` or `["a", "b", "c"]`. With that said, there is a method on the Array object to help with this, `Array#sample` will return a random object from the array. So you might want something like `["a", "b", "c"].sample`. However remember that this will re-roll the selection every time Chef runs which is almost never what you want. If you want something randomized per server but consistent you could do this instead:

```
vals = ["a", "b", "c"]
default["whatever"] = vals[node["shard_seed"] % vals.length]
```

The `shard_seed` attribute comes from Ohai and is a consistent hash based on a number of inputs like the CPU ID and machine UUID.

Comment: Thanks for helping out @coderanger, i'll give this a try